# Access class variable directly with spied instance

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit

Can/Should we access the class member/variable directly while doing JUnit test?

Suppose I have the following class definition:

```
public class ClassA {

    public ClassB classB;
    
    public static class ClassB{
        public String kind;
        public List<ClassC> classc;
        
        public static class ClassC{
            public String id;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I access the class member variable `kind` or userclasses `ClassB` while doing Unit tests?

Can we do the following?

```
ClassA.ClassB spyClassB = spy(ClassA.ClassB.class);
spyClassB.kind = "someValue"; // <== can we do this?
// use spyClassB as needed in the codebase
```

Comment: What is the `spy()` method? `ClassA.ClassB` is invalid java.

Comment: @rzwitserloot sorry, made the edit. I want to spy the ClassB.

Comment: That still doesn't explain whatever `spy` might be. Is it a method from some testing framework, such as mockito's spy? Is it a concept you're asking questions about (in that case, explain what, precisely, you think spy(ClassA.ClassB.class) ought to be returning, etc.

Comment: yes it is mockito's spy @rzwitserloot. I am exactly asking if we should do `spyClassB.kind = "someValue";` in our test case?